# Deleting folder only if it does not contain any files

Tags: python

Is there a way to delete a folder in python if it does not contain any files? I can do the foll:

```
os.rmdir() will remove an empty directory.

shutil.rmtree() will delete a directory and all its contents.
```

If the folder has empty sub-folders, it should be deleted too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**os.removedirs(path)**

> Remove directories recursively. Works like rmdir() except that, if the
>   leaf directory is successfully removed, removedirs() tries to
>   successively remove every parent directory mentioned in path until an
>   error is raised (which is ignored, because it generally means that a
>   parent directory is not empty).

e.g.

```
import os
if not os.listdir(dir):
    os.removedirs(dir)
```

See more details from [os.removedirs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.removedirs).

Hope this helps.